# Verb "fahren" intransitiv vs. transitiv

Tags: verb, perfect-tense

Es geht um das Verb *fahren*.

> Ich **bin** zum Bahnhof gefahren. (intransitiv, Perfekt mit *sein*)
>
> Mein Vater **hat** mich zum Bahnhof gefahren. (transitiv, Perfekt mit
>   *haben*)

Ein Kursteilnehmer hat versucht den folgenden Satz ins Deutsche zu übersetzen und mich gefragt, ob Perfekt mit *haben* oder *sein* gebildet wird:

*I bought a new car and drove it already.*

Die beste Lösung, die ich hatte, war:

*Ich habe mir ein neues Auto gekauft und bin damit schon gefahren.*

Liebe Muttersprachler, lag ich richtig? Kann man *Ich habe mein neues Auto gefahren* sagen ("Auto" als direktes Objekt)? Oder sollte es heißen *Ich bin mit dem Auto gefahren*?

Vielen Dank!

Comment: Sehr interessante Beobachtung, das geht anscheinend bei vielen Bewegunsverben so (reiten, fliegen; aber auch joggen, schwimmen). Erinnert mich an ein [Antipassiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipassiv).

Answer (score 2):

Ja, beides geht.

Ich bin schon damit gefahren (im Deutschen verwendet man statt man *direktes* und *indirektes* Objekt besser Dativ- und Akkusativ-Objekt) ist meiner Meinung nach die etwas gebräuchlichere Lösung, wenn sonst nichts kommt.

Der Akkusativ, also *Ich habe ihn schon gefahren* bietet sich eher für weitere Informationen an: Ich habe das Auto in die Garage gefahren; ich habe das neue Modell schon gefahren.